# Views Rewrite return html string instead of rendering them

Tags: views, theming, 8

I am using Drupal 8.1.3 and in simple views I want to use rewrite feature of views, and I put `<span class="stats">{{ totalcount }}<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>` in rewrite section and on out put I see

[image]

Where is the problem and why view template engine not render HTML in rewrite section?

**UPDATE**
Exactly it that views I try rewrite title field and for it works correctly is seems problem is with statistics total view field !!!

Comment: Can you provide which templates are you using to override your views fields?

Comment: @darol100 I used boostrap theme, but it's not relate to theme because I have the same in the views preview.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be because of the `<i>....</i>` tags part, if you take that out, does it render? Seems like views uses Filter HTML, and only popular html tags are allowed on Custom Fields or Re-Write boxes.

You should be able to achieve your goal by creating a template file.

**views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg0TM.png).html.twig**

```
<span class="stats">{{ fields.totalcount.content }}<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for you attention, it was because statistics field, I try ti add global unformated field then put `<span class="stats">{{ fields.totalcount.content }}<i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-eye"></i></span>` and work correctly. it seems it is a issue in statistics module